# Download bitmap from server to android using php

Tags: php, android, image, download

I want to download an image from my server to an Android app. I have this PHP script:

```
$jpg  = file_get_contents("./images/12345.jpg");

echo $jpg;
```

How can I download this image and show it in an ImageView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must send header before echo :

```
    $filename= "./images/12345.jpg";
    header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header('Content-transfer-encoding: binary');
    header('Content-type: image/jpg');
```

or test it:

```
    $filename= "./images/12345.jpg";
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header('Content-transfer-encoding: binary');
    header('Content-type: image/jpg')
```

;

i hope help you...

Comment: It works in Browser but not in Android, I receive a String but don't know how to transform to bitmap... :(

Comment: do you give file $filename to script ?